# Author-year format for citations in a revtex document

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, revtex

I'm new to bibliographies in LaTeX and I want to be able to use the style as in this [report](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6929). Basically `Rawle et al. (2013)` with and without parentheses so:

```
(Rawle et al. 2013)
Rawle et al.
Rawle et al. (2013)
```

I'm currently using `revtex4` and a `bibtex` file but all that does is just put `[1]` as the citation!

Here's the master tex file:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
\begin{document}
   \title{S0 Galaxies} 
   \date{\today}
   \author{S. Read}
   \affiliation{Department of Physics}
   %\begin{abstract}
   %\end{abstract}
   \maketitle
   %\include{Introduction}

   \cite{dressler_rotational_1983}
   \bibliography{Zotero}
   \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Here is the citation in the bib file (everything else in the bib file is just more citations):

```
@article{dressler_rotational_1983,
title = {Rotational velocities and central velocity dispersions for a sample of S0 galaxies},
volume = {265},
issn = {0004-{637X}},
url = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983ApJ...265..664D},
doi = {10.1086/160712},
abstract = {Field S0 galaxies have bulges exhibiting high rotational velocities similar to those of spiral galaxies, as well as rapidly rotating disks. The Tully-Fisher ({TF)} diagram for field S0s show significant scatter, which indicates that these galaxies are a heterogeneous group in light of disk kinematics. Their spread in the {TF} diagram is larger than that of all Hubble-type spirals, prompting as explanations for such large variation a variation in mass/light ratio, the contamination of disk light by bulge light, and the accidental inclusion of systems lacking true disks whose kinetic energy derives from velocity dispersion rather than rotation. While some S0 galaxies seem to have no disks, their light profiles mimic the extended envelope distinguishing S0s from ellipticals, and they are rotationally flattened. These transition objects may be useful in increasing the present understanding of the formation of spheroidal stellar systems.},
urldate = {2013-10-28},
journal = {The Astrophysical Journal},
author = {Dressler, A. and Sandage, A.},
month = feb,
year = {1983},
keywords = {{ANGULAR} {VELOCITY}, {DISK} {GALAXIES}, {ELLIPTICAL} {GALAXIES}, {GALACTIC} {ROTATION}, {GALACTIC} {STRUCTURE}, {HUBBLE} {DIAGRAM}, {LUMINOSITY}, {SPIRAL} {GALAXIES}, {STELLAR} {SYSTEMS}, {VELOCITY} {DISTRIBUTION}},
pages = {664--680},
file = {NASA/ADS Full Text PDF:C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Zotero\Zotero\Profiles\1lsc8c6m.default\zotero\storage\UTE9FWCU\Dressler and Sandage - 1983 - Rotational velocities and central velocity dispers.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

the `\section{introduction}` consists of: "S0"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe the `natbib` package is helpful. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf

Comment: I've tried natbib (included in revtex4). But it keeps coming up with `Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.`

Comment: Can you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: OK updating question...

Comment: I've moved the instruction "\end{document}" down by two lines so that LaTeX actually sees the instructions "\bibliography{Zotero}" and "\bibliographystyle{plainnat}". I've also commented out the instruction `\input{Introduction}` as it's irrelevant to the problem at hand. Note that numeric citation style is the default for most journals that require the `revtex4` and `revtex4-1` document classes. The `plainnat` bibliography style is, in principle, compatible with both numeric and authoryear citation styles. Which journal do you intend to submit your paper to?

Comment: Thanks. That fixes it. My paper is for University I'm practising latex for it that this was the template but my supervisor wants an author-year thing!

Comment: If you want an author-year citation in a `revtex` document you need to set the citation style for `natbib`, in your preamble add `\setcitestyle{authoryear}`.

Comment: @OSjerick - You should make this comment into an answer.

Comment: @Mico Ok, in a minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `revtex` class loads the `natbib` package with `sort&compress` option, that is for numerical citations. If you want an author-year citation in a `revtex` document, you need to set the citation style for `natbib`, this can be done adding `\setcitestyle{authoryear}`, using this command also you can set the whole style of a citation.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round}%Setting citation style. Changing braces to ()
\begin{document}
    \title{S0 Galaxies}
    \date{\today}
    \author{S. Read}
    \affiliation{Department of Physics}
    \maketitle
    \cite{dressler_rotational_1983}
    \bibliography{Zotero}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Also you can use the `natbib` basic commands `\citet` or `\citep`, or the **extended citation commands** to improve your citation.

Comment: Brilliant but why is there a massive gap between authors in multiple citations: `\cite{dressler_rotational_1983,graham_concise_2005,bedregal_tullyfisher_2006}`? http://pbrd.co/1jy8OnG

Comment: @Lucidnonsense Your document is a twocolumn document. ;)

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks! One last question: why is it that why I use `\include{Introduction}` to put in my separate introduction tex file does everything spread out to 1 section per page? :)

Comment: @Lucidnonsense You're welcome. Read this question: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include), that explains it very well.

Answer (score 0):

The citation style you are looking for is called author-year. It's common in the humanities.

If you're using `biblatex`, you want to use the `apalike` style. If you're using plain old bibtex, you probably want to start with the `apacite` package.

Comment: If I try your suggestion with the OP's file, I get an error message and no authoryear-style citation.