# Is there a way to give in-text authoryear citations but numbered or bulleted citations in the references?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, multiple-citations

I am using REVTeX 4-2, which has the natbib package inbuilt. I am also required to use a BibTeX file, authoryear citation format, and APA citations (currently I am doing that with the apalike style). I would like to have my citations displayed in-text using parenthetical citations, such as

```
as quoted from \citep{smith}.
```

which would give as quoted from (Smith YYYY). However, for the references, I would like to have

```
\bibliography{Biblio.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

and have within it

(1) Smith, J. (YYYY), etc.

or

- Smith, J. (YYYY), etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. I simply used \setcitationstyle{numbers} right before the bibliography.

Comment: You mean \setcitestyle{} cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146712/author-year-format-for-citations-in-a-revtex-document